# UIModalViewController and UIImagePickerController rotation issue

Tags: ipad, rotation, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

This is the situation:
I've a viewController that was presented in this way:

```
AddAttachmentPhotoVideoViewController * addAttachment = [[AddAttachmentPhotoVideoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil attachmentType:AtImage];
addAttachment.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
addAttachment.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
            
[self presentModalViewController:addAttachment animated:YES];
```

in `addAttachment` there is a button that open the camera in this way:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;    
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

The issue is the following: when I rotate the device (iPad) the `imagePicker` rotates itself but the `addAttachment` doesn't rotate; so when I dismiss the picker the `addAttachment` has a wrong frame and it's not rotate properly.

In other words, when the camera is shown, the modal view controller under it, doesn't receive the rotation and so, when I dismiss the picker, the frame of view controller is totally wrong.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must handle the rotation of your ViewController manually.

The foreground ViewController should propagate the rotation message to all ViewControllers behind of it.

Comment: Hi MaTTP, could you provide some code snippet to illustrate the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the `AddAttachmentPhotoVideoViewController` that it should auto-rotate to all interface orientations. By default, `YES` is only returned for portrait orientation. Add the following method to allow auto-rotation to all orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```